# ModelState.IsValid does not exclude required property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im trying to exclude a required property(Password) so the modelstate dont validate that property, but for some reason it still validate even when i try to exclude it.

Controller:

```
    [Authorize, AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult _Edit(int id, [Bind(Exclude = "Password")]FormCollection collection)
    {
        var user = Proxy.GetUser(id);

        TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new[]{"Password"});

        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView(user);

        Proxy.UpdateUser(user);
    }
```

View:

```
   ...
   <tr>
       <td class="label">
           <label class="row_description" for="Password"><%= S._("Password")%></label>
       </td>
       <td>
           <%= Html.Password("Password", null, new { @class = "row_input" })%>
           <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Password", "*")%>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

User(using dataannotation):

```
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Im using VS2008, MVC2, firefox

Maybe im just tired and can't see it. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am currently experiencing a similar issue with MVC3.

Despite `[Bind(Exclude = "Password")]` in my Action, `ModelState.IsValid` still returns false.

I noticed that `TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new string[]{"Password"});` was successfully updating the model; however still returning false. I then found out (somewhere on stackoverflow, apologies for not having the link) that `TryUpdateModel` actually returns `ModelState.IsValid`.

Thus, the issue is not with `TryUpdateModel`, but with `ModelState.IsValid`.

NB: this also means that you do not need to verify this twice... you can use this code:

```
if (!TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new string[]{"Password"}))
    return PartialView(user);
```

The issue thus appears as if ModelState is still validating properties that have been excluded from your `FormCollection`.

I was able to overcome this by removing the field from `ModelState` prior to calling `TryUpdateModel`:

```
ModelState.Remove("Password");
```

Note that TryUpdateModel still requires the list of properties to exclude from the update as per the above code.

Comment: I am also struggling with this.  It seems hackish to perform ModelState.Remove, when it obviously should be excluded.  Can anyone explain exactly why MC3 validaton ignores Bind(Exclude=)?

Comment: @James: I agree, it does seem somewhat counter-intuitive that TryUpdateModel excludes the properties listed in the excludeProperty, but IsValid does not exclude those listed in the Bind(Exclude) (or in the excludeProperty).

Comment: I think I found the answer: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 3):

I had success using the following method within ASP .NET MVC 2

```
TryUpdateModel(user);
ModelState.Remove("Password");
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return PartialView(user);
```

To keep the TryUpdate from binding to certain model properties you can create an inclusion template such as the one below:

```
public interface IUserValidateBindable
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User : IUserValidateBindable
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The update the TryUpodateModel call as follows:

```
TryUpdateModel<IUserValidateBindable>(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension method like so:

```
public static bool IsValidExclude(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, params string[] exclude)
{
    foreach (var key in exclude)
    {
        if (modelState.ContainsKey(key))
            modelState.Remove(key);
    }

    return modelState.All(m => m.Value.Errors.Count == 0);
}
```

Then just call:

```
var result = ModelState.IsValidExclude("Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should replace

```
TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new[]{"Password"});
```

with

```
TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new string[] {"Password"});
```

Because it might be confusing which overload for TryUpdateModel is using.
Just saying...

Comment: Thx for response, but i think my problem is related to me using same model for create and edit. I want password to be required when creating but not when editing. White/black list apparently does not have anything to do with modelstate being valid :D

Answer (score 0):

I used with success `[Bind(Exclude = "Property")]` and `ModelState.Remove("Property")` together, and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I face error on modelstate.isValid with Remove that it does not work for me in webapi asp.net mvc then I track the error

[image]

then I add model `ModelState.Remove("model.Description");` that I defined model as parameter then I used name of parameter and then modelstate works for me like below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I'm replying too late, but I also faced the same problem.

Check your `ModelState.Keys` collection. Keys might be in the form of `modelObjectName.Password` and same for rest of model properties.

So in this case `ModelState.Remove("Password")` will not work. You should try `ModelState.Remove("modelObjectName.Password")`

Hope this resolve someone's issue :)