# `[Bind(Exclude="Password")]` not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I was trying to edit a user page but i dont want to validate the password field. so i put a [Bind(Exclude="Password")] before my model. but it still causes the modelstate.Isvalid to return false. Can anybody know why is that so?

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude="Password")]User user, string selectedStatus, string password, string confirmPassword)
        {
if(ModelState.Isvalid)<---- returns false
{
///logic
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ModelState.IsValid does not exclude required property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166579/modelstate-isvalid-does-not-exclude-required-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This attribute excludes a property from being bound, but not from being validated. So basically the model binder will never assign it a value but if you have validation attributes on it that require a value it won't work.

Obviously the solution to this is to use a view model (which by the way is the solution to about 70% of the questions I am answering on SO related to ASP.NET MVC).

So if you don't want a password field at all simply don't include it in this view model and if you want a password but don't want validation simply don't decorate it with a `Required` attribute.

So instead of:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude="Password")]User user, string selectedStatus, string password, string confirmPassword)
```

use:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditUserViewModel user)
```