# Make MVC not post back one of the members in the model which is an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model that looks like this:

```
class MyViewModel
{
  public string Stuff { get; set; }

  public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The GET requests all work fine because I supply both, `Stuff` and `IFoo` to the view.

However, when posting back, MVC says it can't make an object of an interface.

Now, I have two options:

a) Change the type of the `Foo` property to a concrete implementation, which is no big deal; or

b) Do the model binding myself, which is an overkill for what I want. I really don't care about posting back the `IFoo` member.

How do I tell MVC not to post back IFoo? I don't have any HTML controls also representing the `IFoo`. Properties from the `IFoo`, I use as hidden thingies in the view.

Comment: Maybe you can specify `Exclude` for `Bind` attribute in your POST Action like in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166579/modelstate-isvalid-does-not-exclude-required-property ?

Comment: Hm, I just checked similar code on DotNetFiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/1RJvLw and it works fine. Model with interface passes fine, and interface property is still `null` after binding. Maybe you have some IoC that tries to resolve it for model?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: You are right. I am using UnityContainer. I haven't registered the particular interface with Unity on purpose.

Comment: So the issue is that Unity is trying to resolve this interface. Probably it has custom ModelBinder that does it, because for usual MVC  v4(that works on DotNetFiddle) it works fine. If you are not using injections for model, you can just remove custom Unity Model Binder at startup? It might come from DependencyResolver. MVC might use it for resolving interfaces for models too. And this interface is passed to Unity Dependency Resolver

Comment: I am not using the Unity extensions for MVC, just plain Unity, which does not have a model binder. It does have a dependency resolver mimics MVCs IDependencyResolver, and I have hooked that one in, but I don't want to remove that because I have lots of stuff coming through that one. Also, I am not registering this particular interface with the resolver/container (I might later) because I am still keeping the design of the classes that will implement this interface fluid. It is very early right now. I will later be giving this interface to 3rd parties to write custom impl.

Comment: I bet that if you place breakpoint in your custom resolver during postback, it will hit by DefaultModelBinder that will try to resolve that interface in resolver :) and your custom resolver might throw an exception if type isn't registered instead of returning just null.

Comment: Of course, the trouble is, I don't to register a concrete implementation of my interface just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude properties from binding.

### Via the model

```
[Bind(Exclude="Foo")]
class MyViewModel
{
    public string Stuff { get; set; }

    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

### Via the action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyGreatAction([Bind(Exclude="Foo")]MyViewModel model)
{

}
```

Comment: Sure, please edit your answer and I will mark it the right one. I just checked, as Sergey Litvinov suggests in the comments, the BindAttribute targets class level and parameters only, not methods.

Comment: Ah yeah, I had forgotten slightly how it worked. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, I just realized I could do that myself and edited it anyway. Thank you for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found this link to be of super help to me.. [Custom Model Binder](http://mhwelander.net/2014/03/29/asp-net-mvc-using-a-custom-model-binder-to-post-a-list-of-interface-objects/) But just in case the link goes dead sometime in the future here is the thought process behind it.

> **Posting a list of interfaces**
>
> If you try to post this form, MVC will throw this error: Cannot create an instance of an interface. This is because the default model binder works by creating an instance of your model (and any properties it has) and mapping the posted field names to it; Section.Title maps to the Title property on the Section object, for example. However, Section.SectionFields[0] presents a problem – you cannot create an instance of an interface (or an abstract class).
>
> The solution is to create and register a custom model binder for the IField class...

First create a model binder and inherit from the DefaultModelBinder class:

```
public class IFieldModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
     protected override object CreateModel(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
    Type modelType) {
    // Our work here
        }
 
}
```

Secondly, register it with your application – this is usually done in Application_Start in Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IField), new IFieldModelBinder());
}
```

Next cast each IField into its concrete type. I think she used reflection so she added to properties to her Interface FieldClassName, and FieldAssemblyName. Then she put in 2 hidden fields for Class name and Assembly name in her editor template.

```
@model SectionSummary
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FieldClassName)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FieldAssemblyName)
```

> Now, whenever this particular field is posted, the custom model binder will have the information about the actual type available – which means we can use it to cast the IField object and return a model that can be instantiated.

```
public class IFieldModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
    Type modelType)
    {
 
        // Get the submitted type - should be IField
        var type = bindingContext.ModelType;
 
        // Get the posted 'class name' key - bindingContext.ModelName will return something like Section.FieldSections[0] in our particular context, and 'FieldClassName' is the property we're looking for
        var fieldClassName = bindingContext.ModelName + ".FieldClassName";
 
        // Do the same for the assembly name
        var fieldAssemblyName = bindingContext.ModelName + ".FieldAssemblyName";
 
        // Check that the values aren't empty/null, and use the bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue method to get the actual posted values
 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldClassName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldAssemblyName))
        {
            // The value provider returns a string[], so get the first ([0]) item
            var className = ((string[])bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(fieldClassName).RawValue)[0];
            // Do the same for the assembly name
            var assemblyName =
            ((string[])bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(fieldAssemblyName).RawValue)[0];
 
            // Once you have the assembly and the class name, get the type - I am overwriting the IField object that came in, but I do not think you have to do that
            modelType = Type.GetType(className + ", " + assemblyName);
 
            // Finally, create an instance of this type
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
 
            // Update the binding context's meta data
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => instance, modelType);
 
            // Return the instance - which will now be a SummaryField or CommentField - rather than an IField
            return instance;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> You will now be able to post your List object – for each IField, the custom model binder will be called to figure out what the concrete type of each object is.

Comment: I think model binding is quite a good approach. It's worth noting that the OP said *"[ ... ] model binding myself, which is overkill for what I want"*. Good answer anyway.

Comment: @RowanFreeman yeah good point, I missed that. I saw the problem and it sparked a memory.