# Enum Dropdown value required error in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there any way to make an enum's dropdownlist optional? When the form posts with no value for this dropdown, `ModelState.IsValid` evaluates to `false` with an error that a value is required for this dropdown. I have not explicitly used `[Required]` attribute on this property.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.People[0].Role, "Select a role", new { @class = "form-control role" })
```

The enum is:

```
public enum RoleType { Employee, Visitor, Vendor, Witness }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the property m.People[0].Role nullable in your model. You can set the RoleType to be nullable and this should remove the validation error.

```
public RoleType? Role {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a way that you can remove specific properties from the ModelState by using something like

```
ModelState.Remove("nameOfProperty");
```

This info was found on another Stackoverflow post at the following link

[ModelState.IsValid does not exclude required property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166579/modelstate-isvalid-does-not-exclude-required-property)

Not sure if this relates directly to your issue, but hope this helps.