# Best practice to design a ViewModel containing display data and binding data for HttpGet and HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been reading StackOverflow for quite a while now and it's time for my first post:

I'm currently using C# / ASP.NET Core 3.1. What's the best practice to design a ViewModel containing display data and binding data for HttpGet and HttpPost. I found some discussions on keeping display and binding data separated or not separated but without any examples. The problem with using the same ViewModel on HttpPost (without binding attributes) is that Display Data references get an invalid modelstate because they are of course null in the incoming model.

I usually tend to use the following stripped-down code. Is inheritance the way to go or any other sort of pattern? Or is it better to put everything in the view model with binding attributes for non-binding data?

Thanks all!

```
public class CMyBindModel
{
  public int ProductQuantity ( get; set; }    // Binding Data

  // Other Binding properties ...
}

public class CMyViewModel : CMyBindModel
{
  public string ProductName ( get; set; }    // Display Data

  // Other Display properties ...
}
```

---

```
public IActionResult Cart ()
{
  CMyViewModel viewModel = BuildViewModel () ;
  return View (viewModel) ;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Cart (CMyBindModel bindModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    SetProductQuantity (bindModel.ProductQuantity) ;
    return RedirectToAction ("Cart") ;
  }

  CMyViewModel viewModel = BuildViewModel () ;
  return View (viewModel) ;
}
```

---

```
Cart.cshtml

@model CMyViewModel

<div>@Model.ProductName</div>

<form method="post" asp-area="" asp-controller="CartController" asp-action="Cart">
  <input asp-for="ProductQuantity" />
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your first models describes what a request looks like. Your view model describes what you need to render a view. Both may look similar but they are clearly responsible for different things. That said: I would use two classes. No inheritance. If you need parts from your request in your view, copy the properties. - just my 5 cent.

Comment: There are a few strategies here. I’ve frequently used the inheritance approach you outline, and especially when each view model is specific to the underlying binding model. For instance, if a `User` entity has a read-only `DateJoined` property which should be displayed, that’s a good use case for a `UserViewModel`. For areas where the view models have a common set of properties used across binding models, I instead use a generic view model, with a generic binding model property. That accommodates common read-only metadata and shared user interface elements such as `PageTitle`, `LastModified`.

Comment: Thanks very much all for your suggestions. Yes, I guess that different strategies are useful in different situations (Inheritance, Separate Models, ModelState.Remove, ...). Purists might disagree with the inheritance solution because most of the time, it's not an isA relationship. I seldom use 2 separate models but I recently had a model containing a list of shop class containing a list of product class to be displayed with some binding properties in each class - 2 separate models for View and Binding solve my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem on using the same ViewModel on HttpPost (without binding attributes) is that Display Data references get an invalid modelstate because they are of course null in the incoming model.

By using the same ViewModel(here is `CMyViewModel`),you could overcome the validation error by removing the field from `ModelState` prior to judging `ModelState.IsValid`.

Refer to my simple demo:

Model:

```
public class CMyViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }  // Binding Data

    // Other Binding properties ...

    [Required]
    public string ProductName{get; set; }    // Display Data

    // Other Displaying properties ...
}
```

Actions:

```
public void RemoveDisplayingDataValidation()
{
    ModelState.Remove("ProductName");
    //remove other Displaying properties' validation
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Cart(CMyViewModel viewModel)
{
    RemoveDisplayingDataValidation();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SetProductQuantity (viewModel.ProductQuantity) ;
        return RedirectToAction("Cart");
    }

    CMyViewModel viewModel = BuildViewModel () ;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Refer to [ModelState.IsValid does not exclude required property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166579/modelstate-isvalid-does-not-exclude-required-property)

Besides, Christoph Lütjen's suggestion of using two models separately also will work.